# Start tomcat7 in debug mode when running as a service

Tags: debugging, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

Im running tomcat7 as a service in ubuntu 12.04. I just need to start it in debug mode.in a previous post they have asked to put the debugging options in /etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf. But i cannot find the tomcat7.conf in /etc/tomcat7 folder. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about _remote_ debugging? http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1

Comment: Yes.. but i cannot use catalina jpda start as i have installed tomcat as package. im starting it as service tomcat7 start

Comment: No.. There is not tomcat7.conf in /etc/tomcat7

Comment: If you installed with `apt-get` it may be installed under `/usr/share/tomcat7`

Comment: In /usr/share/tomcat7 i have " bin  defaults.md5sum  defaults.template  lib "

Comment: Okay, third time is the charm: how about `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf`

Comment: It has the same files/folders as /etc/tomcat7. "Catalina  catalina.properties  context.xml  logging.properties  policy.d  server.xml  tomcat-users.xml  web.xml
" . no tomcat7.conf

Comment: yish! Sorry I can't be more help - you might want to try http://askubuntu.com/